# MySQL Join tables, if criteria not met still return as null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySQL query

```
SELECT perms.permission_id, perms.long_title, perms.category, gperms.value FROM
acl_permissions AS perms JOIN acl_group_permissions AS gperms ON
(perms.permission_id = gperms.permission_id AND gperms.group_id = 1) WHERE
perms.type IN ('adm', 'cs') AND perms.simple_title NOT IN ('adm_', 'cs_')
ORDER BY perms.long_title
```

Basically the bit causing problems is in the `ON`. I want the query to return all rows from `perms` based on the where criteria regardless of whether there is a row matching `gperms.group_id = 1`.

`gperms.value` would ideally just be an empty string if there was no row matching `gperms.group_id = 1`.

Comment: Seems MySQL doesn't support outer join, so would have to use a complicated work around.

Comment: Ah reading this with the answer below, I guess you were meaning left outer join, I assumed I was looking for full outer join after a couple google searches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (or `LEFT JOIN` for short) gperms instead of just a straight join

```
SELECT perms.permission_id, perms.long_title, perms.category, gperms.value 
FROM acl_permissions AS perms 
LEFT JOIN acl_group_permissions AS gperms 
    ON (perms.permission_id = gperms.permission_id AND gperms.group_id = 1) 
WHERE perms.type IN ('adm', 'cs') 
    AND perms.simple_title NOT IN ('adm_', 'cs_')
ORDER BY perms.long_title
```

which will return `NULL` for gperms.value for any row that doesn't join the gperms on the given condition.

If you want an empty string instead of the `NULL` you can use `IFNULL()`:

```
SELECT perms.permission_id, perms.long_title, perms.category, IFNULL(gperms.value,'')
```

Comment: Bingo! Exactly what I'm looking for. Didn't think the solution would be so simple.

Comment: +1 Gotta admit, i never got the hang of inner and outer and stuff, but your solution saved me a lot of time... of course... after a few wasted hours looking for an answer.